# Anthy (uim) doesn't convert anything?

Tags: 18.04, input-method, japanese

`Anthy`, the Japanese input method, doesn't convert anything. That is, I can't type any katakana or kanji. I'm using `uim`, and I set "begin conversion" hotkey as Space Bar.

I tried converting "はんどる" to katakana by pressing Space, and it didn't work.
I tried converting "いちにち" to kanji by pressing Space, and it also didn't work.

Why?

Comment: すみいません、"uim"はなんですか。.....

Comment: If you are willing to switch to `mozc`, "はんどる" and "いちにち" get converted to ハンドル and 一日 out-of-the-box without configuration by pressing <kbd>space</kbd>. I haven't used `Anthy` for years because `mozc` is so much better.

Comment: @GreatUncleBulgaria `uim` is a multilingual input method framework. It includes `Anthy`.

Comment: Perhaps just Anthy or ibus-Anthy would work better. Never had any problems with those packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `m17b` has some problems. I just installed `uim-anthy`, which does the job finely.